# Trying to install asyncawait module, always fails and comes back with the same error

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install the `asyncawait` module by using `npm install asyncawait`. However it keeps failing on me, and it looks like its to do with the `node-gyp` module, but I've installed the latest version on my mac. I can't figure out how to fix it, it used to work fine. Here's the error log:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!

> fibers@2.0.2 install /Users/MyUser/Documents/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
../src/fibers.cc:318:3: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with
      'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
                object->SetAccessor(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), name, ...
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/fibers.cc:464:24: warning: 'Utf8Value' is deprecated: Use Isolate version
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                                        String::Utf8Value stack(uni::Der...
                                                          ^
/Users/MyUser/.node-gyp/11.7.0/include/node/v8.h:2991:5: note: 'Utf8Value' has
      been explicitly marked deprecated here
    V8_DEPRECATED("Use Isolate version",
    ^
/Users/MyUser/.node-gyp/11.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded
      from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../src/fibers.cc:686:66: error: too few arguments to function call, expected at
      least 2, have 1
  ...Script::Compile(uni::NewLatin1String(that.isolate, "void 0;"));
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                              ^
/Users/MyUser/.node-gyp/11.7.0/include/node/v8.h:1359:3: note: 'Compile'
      declared here
  static V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Script> Compile(
  ^
../src/fibers.cc:701:66: error: too few arguments to function call, single
      argument 'context' was not specified
  ...uni::Reset(that.isolate, fatal_stack, try_catch.StackTrace());
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/MyUser/.node-gyp/11.7.0/include/node/v8.h:8878:3: note: 'StackTrace'
      declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> StackTrace(
  ^
/Users/MyUser/.node-gyp/11.7.0/include/node/v8config.h:418:31: note: expanded
      from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
2 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/MyUser/Documents/pws/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v11.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
sh: nodejs: command not found
npm WARN mobx-react@5.4.3 requires a peer of mobx@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN mobx-react@5.4.3 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dropdown@1.6.3 requires a peer of react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-dropdown@1.6.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-hot-loader@4.6.3 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-hot-loader@4.6.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-tabs@2.3.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-alpha.41 requires a peer of mobx@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-alpha.41 requires a peer of react@^16.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-alpha.41 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN redoc@2.0.0-alpha.41 requires a peer of styled-components@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! fibers@2.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@2.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Do you have an actual use case for using the `asyncawait` library instead of native async/await?

Comment: Actually I don't now, it's just left in from when native async/await didn't work on the system. It's would be easier to leave it in, if it wasn't for this problem. It seems to only affect my computer though, others and our build server have no problem installing it

Comment: Fair enough. You'll find a few similar issues on the Github for this library, such as [this one](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait/issues/65) and [this other one](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait/issues/69), all related to the install of the `fibers` package, much like your problem.
Keep in mind the usage of native async/await as an eventual last resort, but looking through the [Github issues](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=build) with the search keyword "build" might work for you.